# Mongoose dynamic sub document schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an Inquiry schema:

```
const inquirySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  client: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client' }],
  data: dynamicSchema?
}, {
  timestamps: true
});
```

I would like to populate the "data" property field with a sub-document, but I want it to accept different sub-document schemas. I have an "Event" and a "Property" child schema which can be inserted as "data". How do I allow this in my Inquiry schema? It seems I have to actually specify WHICH sub-document schema it expects...

My Child schemas:

```
const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { min: Number, max: Number },
  date: { type: Date },
  zone: { type: String }
});

const propertySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  price: { min: Number, max: Number },
  status: { type: String },
  zone: { type: String }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make your `data` as `type : ObjectId` without defining any reference in the schema, and when you want to populate them, use `path` and `model` in the `populate` to `populate` from different `collection`, but you must have a `logic` for choosing which `collection` to `populate` from.

Here is how you can do the same:

**inquirySchema**

```
const inquirySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  client: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client' }],
  data: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});
```

**Populating `data`**

```
if(isEvent)
{
    //Populate using Event collection
    Inquiry.find({_id : someID}).
            populate({path : 'data' , model : Event}).
            exec(function(err,docs){...});
}
else if(isProperty)
{
    //Populate using Property collection
    Inquiry.find({_id : someID}).
            populate({path : 'data' , model : Property}).
            exec(function(err,docs){...});
}
```